# Is it possible to work on a team where some use Xamarin IDE and others Visual Studio?

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We want to develop a multi-platform mobile application which works on `iOS` (`iPad` and `iPhone`), `Android` and `Windows Phone`.

To do this we have one person that wants to use a `Mac` with `Xamarin IDE` and one person who wants to use `Windows 7` and `Visual Studio` with `Xamarin` plugin.

In the end the code needs to be compiled towards native `iOS`, `Android` and `Windows Phone` code. We use `Git` for source control.

Is it possible to collaborate on the same project and compile the code for all platforms with the `Xamarin` plugin for `Visual Studio`?

Comment: As noted by Pete and Jason, it is absolutely possible. I switch between Xamarin Studio (Mac and Windows) and VS while the rest of my team uses Visual Studio. There have been no issues in this approach so far (this is a several month project).

Comment: Hi @MattR, I've seen your profile for your LinkedIn address.  If your very much involved in the Xamarin.Forms area, then I'd be very interested in hearing from you.  My contact details are on my Profile if you would like to get in contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - this should be possible, although I haven't specifically tried this with **Xamarin Studio** running on the **Mac**, and **Visual Studio** running on **Windows**.

I tend to switch often between **Xamarin Studio** and **Visual Studio** on **Windows**, on the *same machine*, due to various issues with **Xamarin** and have no issues as such when passing the same project back and forth.

The desired outcome that you want should still be the same regardless of the **OS** your are working on.  Solution files should be compatible, interchangeably between the two **OS**.  When you add new files on a **Mac**, and check in the files, the other user's will simply have to download the latest project files and then be able to compile the solution locally, and vice versa.

Should you switch between the two IDEs on the same **PC**, although this is not what your particular asking (as you will just have one editor open at a time on a machine) - it is still worth noting that should a new file be added to the solution in **Xamarin Studio**, then the file will automatically be detected and prompted for reloading into **Visual Studio**.  The reverse, however, is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question I cannot seem to get an answer to: Is Xamarin Studio a FREE product? I know that the plugin for Visual Studio is only free for 90 days, but what about Xamarin Studio for Mac? From my understanding you need a XCode subscription to publish apps, but you can you use it for free. Am I correct in this?

Comment: For publishing apps you will need to purchase an Apple developer subscription.  XCode, itself, I believe is free on Mac.  Hopefully someone else can confirm on whether Xamarin Studio is free or not as I am not sure myself as I've always had a license for Xamarin.  For the iOS / Android binaries etc of Xamarin, you do definitely need some sort of license however and if you want to continue receiving the updates they publish then you will need to continue the license.  If your unclear then perhaps contact Xamarin for clarification?  I'm sure they would be willing to help out?

Comment: Thanks. I've send a question to Xamarin.

Comment: I guess Xamarin offers a free license to indie developers but there is a limit on how much code you can compile - you can build just small apps that cannot P/Invoke third-party libraries. Companies must pay. [Source](https://store.xamarin.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  I am currently working on a project where some users use VS and some of us use XS.  The Solution/Project files should be compatible so there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'll chime in as well; we have projects switching between VS and XS and Windows/OSX with no issues.